# Return a html tag with substr JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, substring, substr

I want to add this html tag `<a href="#">Read More</a>` after following jquery

```
$("span.fine-print").text(function(index, currentText) {
       if (currentText.length > 200) {
         return currentText.substr(0, 200)+'...';

    }
});
```

How to add that "Read More" link after this.
Any help highly appriciate. Thanks,

Comment: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamically-shortened-text-show-more-link-jquery/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use the `html()` method to get and insert HTML, the `text()` method only works with ... text.

```
$("span.fine-print").html(function(index, currentHTML) {
    if (currentHTML.length > 200) {
        return currentHTML.substr(0, 200) + '...<a href="#">Read More</a>';
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/5mf64ok2/)

Comment: It's woking for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var currentText = $(".fine-print").text();
if(currentText.length > 10) {
  $("span.fine-print").html(currentText.substr(0, 10)+'  <a href="#" class="readmore">Read More </a>');
  $(".readmore").click(function(){
    $("span.fine-print").html(currentText);
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="fine-print"> Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum </span>
```